# How to say things are different from one another

Tags: grammar, usage, preposition

Lately I have been confused on how to say different in Mandarin. I learned 不同 and 不一样 but am not confident on their usage. I am also unsure of the grammar. I found 与众不同 but this seems to also have the meaning of a grade above, or unusual in a good way.

Should I use 跟、和、像 or 与？ What is the difference?

Are there other ways to say something is different?

Is 没有人想跟同辈不同 an accurate translation of "No one likes to be different from their peers"？

Comment: I suppose a 同被 would also be a kind of peer, although a _very_ intimate one!

Answer (score 2):

"众" stands for everything/everyone. 跟、和、像 or 与 are prepositions. 与众不同 means diff from everything/everyone. There are several ways to say "be diff from something" in Mandarin, for examples: 与something不同/和something不一样/跟something不一样(substitute "something" with the one you want to say in Mandarin). These sentences have the same meaning. However, 像 is seldom used with "不同" or "不一样". "异" also has the meaning of "different/difference", but usually used in a differently way. For your last question, I assume you might mistype one thing, since a more appropriate way to translate would be "没有人想跟同辈不同".